# Is there a PHP function for imploding an associative array without losing the keys?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

The title of this question is self-explanatory.

I've heard I can mimic this using http_build_query, but I'd rather use a function that's meant for this.

---

Input example:

```
$assoc = array(
    "fruit" => "banana",
    "berry" => "blurberry",
    "vegetable" => "lettice"
);
```

Desired output (I get this with http_build_query):

```
string(46) "fruit=banana,berry=blurberry,vegetable=lettice"
```

output from reversal wanted is the same as input - that's my current problem.

Comment: can you give an input/output example?

Comment: http_build_query is meant for that, in a way. To echo Hannes, what is it you'd like to have returned?

Comment: I believe the word is "lettuce," though "blurberry" sounds awesome.

Comment: how about `function implode_array_with_keys($array) {return http_build_query($array,'',',')}` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implode with

```
serialize($array);
```

Explode with

```
unserialize($array);
```

Comment: Output doesn't match what I'd prefer, but otherwise it's perfect and I ended up using this.

Answer (score 0):

Found a function in the `php` `.net` comments for [`implode`](http://theserverpages.com/php/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
function implode_with_key($glue = null, $pieces, $hifen = ',') {
    $return = null;
    foreach ($pieces as $tk => $tv) $return .= $glue.$tk.$hifen.$tv;
    return substr($return,1);
}
```