# Remove array keys to be left with just data

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array from a database, I just want to be left with the `productnames` without the array structure to be shown.

```
public function selectAll () 
{
    $stmt = Database::get()->query('SELECT `productname` FROM retrofootball_products');
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

The output of this is

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [productname] => Manchester City 1981 Centenary FA Cup Final Shirt ) [1] => Array ( [productname] => Manchester City 1999 Playoff Winning Shirt ) )
```

I want to be left with

```
Manchester City 1981 Centenary FA Cup Final Shirt, Manchester City 1999 Playoff Winning Shirt
```

Comment: Same as this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821391/is-there-a-php-function-for-imploding-an-associative-array-without-losing-the-ke

Comment: If I understand you want to return just a string. I don't think there's a way to do it. Breaks the idea of columns. Just dereference it (5.4 can do it without temporary variables)

Comment: Just tried serialize() and just seem to remove the array from the screen.

Answer (score 4):

If you want comma separated use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Answer (score 1):

You may use [implode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.implode.php) :

```
implode(',', $smt->fetchAll(PDO::FECTH_ASSOC));
```